# How to bind css properties between elements?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I want element A to have a the same width as element B. whenever B changes, A should change as well.

What is the angularjs way of doing it?

Here is a fiddle to illustrate my problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/6684/

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="blue" style="width: {{ // how do I get the red div's width? }}px"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you change the width of the first `div`?

Comment: @putvande only on window resize

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not applying the width to the parent element? [Like this](http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/ADukg/6685/). Also, if you change `width` to `min-width` and `max-width`, you might not need javascript to control the width.

Comment: @Joonas actually, i oversimplified. it's not really that simple. Please try to answer my question: how to bind css using angularjs

Comment: I'm still not satisfied that this can't be done with just css...

Comment: does it work for you http://jsfiddle.net/p9rtj18h/ ?

Answer (score 0):

I hope the below link helps

http://plnkr.co/edit/h9MsdAUk0AFloHQu5eNu?p=preview

HTML code

```
  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <div id='red' class="red"></div>
      <div class="blue" ng-style="{width:{{getRedWidth()}}}"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Script.js file

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function mainController($scope){

  $scope.getRedWidth = function (){

    var red = document.getElementById('red');
    var redWidth = red.offsetWidth;
    console.log(redWidth);
    return "'"+redWidth+"px'";
  }
});
```

Comment: That uses jQuery. You might as well not use Angular at all.

Comment: @putvande Since the user Moshe did not mention anything about another element (red), How it changes the width, It is hard to give me the exact answer. But ng-style is the angular way of styling. I removed the dependency of jquery and updated my plnkr link